# Custom UIStoryboardSegue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm writing a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` to animate the transitions between views. When a segue is triggered, each controller (source and destination) is asked to animate accordingly. Here's how:

```
- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController * sourceViewController = [self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController * destinationViewController = [self destinationViewController];
    UIViewController * containerViewController = [self containerViewController];

    UIView * sourceView = sourceViewController.view;
    UIView * destinationView = destinationViewController.view;
    UIView * containerView = containerViewController.view;

    // The container view is as large as the union of the two other views
    CGRect sourceFrame = sourceView.frame;
    CGRect destinationFrame = destinationView.frame;
    CGRect containerFrame = CGRectUnion(sourceFrame, destinationFrame);

    [containerView setFrame:containerFrame];

    // The two views are presented in a container view; this way no one fights about who gets what
    [sourceView removeFromSuperview];
    [containerView addSubview:sourceView];
    [containerView addSubview:destinationView];

//    [sourceViewController presentViewController:containerViewController animated:NO completion:^{
//        NSLog(@"done presenting");
//    }];
//    NSLog(@"done calling presenting");

    id <HyTransition> presentingTransition = [self presentingTransitionForViewController:destinationViewController];
    id <HyTransition> dismissingTransition = [self dismissingTransitionForViewController:sourceViewController];

    // Perform the transitions
    [presentingTransition performWithTransitionContext:self.presentingContext];
    [dismissingTransition performWithTransitionContext:self.dismissingContext];
}
```

The problem is when presenting the containing view. It works well if the source view controller is a standard view controller, but not if it's `UINavigationController` or others of the kind, which don't add their views to the view hierarchy. When doing so, I get this:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <HyPresentationViewController: 0x7fdac2d34b60> on <HyRootController: 0x7fdac2e28590> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

How can I present the containing view?

Edit: notice that I do not require a containing view controller - a containing view is enough.